# How can I make a Windows Form pass a command to the console/command line?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, win32gui

I have created a new Windows Forms Application

Looks like picture (simplified)

[image]

...

Also I have a command line program (python)

It is saved in path as "myApp"

To run it, just need to type "myApp" (and pass it options) on command line

...

This is great, but I also want someone not familiar/comfortable with command line to

be able to use the program. Hence the form.

...

So question is, how can I set it up, such that on button click,

the **form does the equivalent** of typing directly to command line ??

...

I think this is possible because if I start a New Console Application, and code

```
system("myApp");
```

It does exactly this

...

However when I use the 'system' code in Windows Forms, I get a

```
'system': identifier not found
```

error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` method to run any Windows cmd command, like starting it from the command line.

Sample code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("py script.py");
```

[MSDN Official Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the quick reply!
When I use it, I get an 

`error C2882: 'System' : illegal use of namespace identifier in expression`

Perhaps because I am using a .h file vs a .vb??

Comment: Do you already have a namespace in your code called `System`? Compile error C2882 shows me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/96c84dtx.aspx

Comment: I see, I see thanks! Will post back in a bit gonna read through the links provided

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Process` class with an appropriately set up `ProcessStartInfo`. There's a detailed example at [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If thats the case i think we will have to do it the hard way.You could compile a seperate dll in visual studio to do exactly what your console application did,like
    system("fileneme")

and then set it to dynamically link with your form application at run time, and hopefully you will get it right.

Comment: Don't you think,this idea is overcomplicating the logic a bit ?

Comment: That certainly might not be the simplest.But it's a sure shot.